# Change "XX:XX:00" to "00:XX:XX"

Tags: excel

So I have this data directly copy/paste from iTunes : [image]

Excel have "`XX:XX:00`" format which is "`hh:mm:ss`" but as you can imagine, it is more like "`mm:ss:00`". Musics are not hours long !

As it's not a direct cell format problem, I couldn't find easily the answer on internet. I need sometihng to put the 2 "`00`" at the start (in order to have "`00:mm:ss`")

EDIT : It was a cell format comprehension problem.

Comment: Assuming you already have `11:42`, what would be wrong with `"00:"&C2`?

Comment: It is giving me "00:0,4875".
It is a format problem (tought it wasn't but...) as the "Durée" column, in text format give me "0,4875"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide the cell value to 60 like so

[image]

and then choose custom format for that cell like this

[image]

Comment: It works well !Asuming that excel convert 1 as 24h, I understand why 0,4875 is 11:42 and why I can just divide by 60 to have minutes instead of hours.

Comment: @mewXMax Excel keeps _11:42_ as _0.4875_ in the cell (you see it as _11:42_). _0.4875 / 60 = 0.008125_ and that is the value of the other cell. When you format it as time, it shows _00:11:42_

Answer (score 1):

This formula should work:

```
="00:" & MID(TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"),SEARCH(":",TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"))+1,3) & RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"),2)
```

The important element is to convert the time into a text string.

- Change A1 to the first cell of Duration (Duree) & copy the formula downward
- Then, you can copy the result and paste it as values

Edit: you can also use just the right function:

```
="00:"&RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"),LEN(TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"))-SEARCH(":",TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss")))
```

Comment: You can't be more right with what you said but after replacing every functions by their French brother, I have something very close of what I wanted : `00:42:00` 
So I think I'll be able, with your formula, to find what I wanted.

When I'll have it, I'll come back in order to answer the question.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added another option to the answer because you only need the right function for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell with the time (C1) as "General". If it retains its value, like 11:42, then convert it with *=TimeValue(C1)* and format the cell as Custom *mm:ss*

If it changes to something like 0.4875 then convert it with *=C1/60* and format the result as Custom *mm:ss*

Comment: It will change to _0.4875_ every time, if it changed _11:42_ to _11:42:00_

Comment: Divide 0.4875 by 60 to convert hours to minutes. Then format the cell as Time.